# Get public posts on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dataset

I'm doing a research and I wanna create a dataset formed by Facebook posts. The problem is that I can't retrieve public posts,
It seems like Facebook doesn't allow to retrieve public data, so I don't know how to do it.
If anybody knows how I can get public posts from public pages I'll be thankful.

I tried with the Facebook Graph API but if I want to retrieve the posts of a page it asks me for the page-id which i don't know where to get it. Also there's seem to be a problem with the authorization once i make the requests.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started/#:~:text=The%20pages_show_list%20permission-,Step%201.%20Get%20Your%20Page%20ID,-Send%20a%20GET

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't allow just any arbitrary access to public data via API any more.

Your app would have to get the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/page-public-content-access) feature approved.

But the only allowed use case they list is "[to] provide competitive benchmark analysis", so whether they would approve it for your intended usage, you'd have to see.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook surely allows public posts to be fetched. You said it yourself, all you need is the page ID. To get a page ID, Meta suggests you start [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started/#:%7E:text=The%20pages_show_list%20permission-,Step%201.%20Get%20Your%20Page%20ID,-Send%20a%20GET). In order to utilize that endpoint however, you will need a user ID. The user ID is present in the URL for any given user page.

Leverage **URLSearchParams** to grab the ID from the search bar, and then pass that ID to the Page endpoint query.

I recommend playing around with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=US&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=0IRa7z3BlGGUqpAqS&max_percent_page_viewed=62&max_viewport_height_px=937&max_viewport_width_px=1920&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fpages%2Fgetting-started%2F&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dpages%26path2%3Dgetting-started&region=noam&scrolled=true&session_id=0U5FOTnkGypJ3TlU4&site=developers) tool that will generate code snippets via an interactive UI.